# Given members $x$, $y$ of subroup $HN$, show that $xy^{-1} \in HN$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H$ and $N$ be subgroups of a group $G$, with $N$ normal in $G$.
>   It is given that $HN$, the subset of $G$ consisting of elements of the
>   form $hn$, where $h \in H$ and $n \in N$, is a subgroup of $G$.
>
> Given members $x$, $y$ of subgroup $HN$, show that $xy^{-1} \in HN$.

I'm looking for something more rigorous than just "$HN$ is a subgroup and thus closed under inverses and products."

So $N$ normal in $G$ means $\forall a \in N, \forall g \in G, gag^{-1} \in N$. However I'm not sure how to proceed from there. What's a good way to show $xy^{-1} \in HN$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x=hn$ and $y=h'n'$, then $xy^{-1}=hnn'^{-1}h'^{-1}=hh'^{-1}(h'nn'h'^{-1})$

Comment: Can you please explain that last step?

Comment: $hh'\in H$ and $h'(nn')h'^{-1}\in N$ ($N$ normal), hence $xy^{-1}\in HN$